# How do I reset a variable so that another If statement can use it?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have data from every month of the year, with each month split into two 15 day worksheets.

I'm trying to sum the two worksheets and then put the value into a compilation worksheet then moving on to the next month.

As it stands it just adds everything starting from January, I've tried resetting it to 0 but that just results in everything being zero.

I could easily just apply a formula at the end of the code that applies a subtraction of the previous cells but I figured it'd be better to learn how to do it in VBA. Perhaps I'm just not using the right words in google.

Thanks for the help.

```
Sub Sum()

Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim destrow As Long
Dim prevval As Double
Dim nextval As Double

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Deletes Compilation worksheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compilation").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Compilation"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    'loop through all worksheets
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Loop through all worksheets except Compilation
        If IsError(Application.Match(Sh.Name, _
                                     Array(DestSh.Name), 0)) Then

        'Check for the last column on row 6
        lastcol = Sh.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Check for the last row that the last column above has
        lastrow = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, lastcol).End(xlUp).Row

            'Checks if Cell B3, contains JAN and then enters the contents to DestSh
            If Sh.Cells(3, 2).Value Like "*JAN*" Then
                destrow = DestSh.Cells(3, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    prevval = prevval
                    nextval = prevval + Sh.Cells(lastrow, lastcol).Value
                DestSh.Cells(destrow + 2, 2).Value = nextval
                    prevval = nextval
            End If
            If Sh.Cells(3, 2).Value Like "*FEB*" Then
                destrow = DestSh.Cells(3, 3).End(xlUp).Row
                    prevval = prevval
                    nextval = prevval + Sh.Cells(lastrow, lastcol).Value
                DestSh.Cells(destrow + 2, 3).Value = nextval
                    prevval = nextval
            End If
        End If
    Next
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can store the intermediate values on DestSh - just add the second value to the existing value on that sheet.  It's a little unclear why you're using End(xlUp) to find where to place the summary values though: if the sheet is empty you could use fixed locations and your code would be clearer.

Comment: @TimWilliams do you mean something like

 `DestSh.Cells(destrow + 2, 3).Value = DestSh.Cells(destrow + 2, 3).Value + sh.Cells(lastrow, lastcol).Value` ?

Actually that works. why didn't I think of that...

Answer (score 1):

Well in light of my novice myopia I didn't quite see the obvious. Thanks @TimWilliams

Changed the formatting to the if and then statements to this:

```
If Sh.Cells(3, 2).Value Like "*JAN*" Then
     destrow = DestSh.Cells(3, 2).Row
     DestSh.Cells(destrow, 2).Value = DestSh.Cells(destrow, 2).Value _
        + Sh.Cells(lastrow, lastcol).Value
End If
```